# How to make subscirpt or superscript for all letters in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I need to put some chemical data into a table. But I realized that unicode hasn´t got subscript/superscript code for all characters in alphabet.

For example I´m trying to type "org" ("C_org" - organic carbon) as subscript into column  but "g" subscript is not classified by unicode as well as some other letters like "n, f, etc.

Any solution?

Thank you much.

Comment: Perhaps using some sort of markup like HTML for this?

Comment: could you please add some sample data ?

Comment: It seems that html markup is the only way
INSERT INTO [dbo].[c_chem] (id, label, description, valid_from)  
VALUES  ('100', 'C<sub>inorg</sub>', 'volume of bonded inorganic carbon', GETDATE()),

Comment: It's most defiantly **not** the only way, however it's probably the easiest way to do it. you can use whatever markup that suit your needs, even create your own markup. HTML is just a standard.

Comment: Michael you can use this method to get Unicode value of a character  `select UNICODE(N'₂')` and then select like this `SELECT N'H' + NCHAR(0x2082) + N'O'`;

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out there is a [Chemical Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_Markup_Language) that is based on XML.
If you don't want to use this, you can use whatever markup language you want, or even create your own markup.
If the only thing you need to markup is subscript and superscript, use can use something as simple as `<b>` for su**b**script`</b>` and `<p>`for su**p**erscript`</p>`.